# Constants in the triggers in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

I'm trying to create a trigger in MySQL. I need to use some values (constants) at several times within the trigger. How can I define a constant in order to make my trigger more maintainable and don't have numeric values spread along the code.

(Maybe is an stupid question but I'm a starter with MySQL)

Thanks in advance

Comment: [`DECLARE var_name value`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/declare-local-variable.html)

Answer (score 1):

As NullUserException stated, DECLARE is what you need. (The syntax he indicated is wrong however).

The syntax is

```
DECLARE var_name type DEFAULT value;
```

example

```
DECLARE someConstant int DEFAULT 10;
```

if you leave off DEFAULT the initial value will be NULL. (IE: DECLARE var_name type;)